# Kusto sort vs order

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I ve been through the official doc of 
[Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sortoperator) and [Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/orderoperator). But there isn't a clear difference on what sort and order does differently.

Just wanted to confirm if they are one and the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both operators are equivalent (the documentation you've linked to mentions that they're aliases)

Answer (score 0):

There is a small difference I found.
When I use 'ORDER BY' on a float column in either descending or ascending order, it doesn't always behave as expected (I suspect this occurs when the row size is too large).
However, 'SORT BY' does work in such situations.